# Adding a flat image overlay on google maps using GroundOverlay: how to calculate imagebounds?

Tags: javascript, maps

I'm trying to achieve a very simple thing: add a png image overlay to google maps.

The documentation page seems very straight forward: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/groundoverlays#introduction

What it basically says: pick a center position on the map (lat, lng), specify the url for the image overlay, and specify the image bounds.

The problem I have is that I have no idea how to calculate the image bounds. I've tried guessing, adding/subtracting 3 from lat/lng but it doesn't seem to work.

I have specified a different center lat/lng for the map than the example provided, and my image overlay just won't show up.

Any ideas?

This is the code:
https://jsfiddle.net/rwtpmq12/

```
let historicalOverlay;
function initMap(): void {
const map = new google.maps.Map(
document.getElementById("map") as HTMLElement,
{
  zoom: 18,
  center: { lat: 41.749683140196, lng: 44.709563513388915 },
}
);
const initLat = 41.749683140196;
const initLng  = 44.709563513388915;
const imageBounds = {
north: initLat +3,
south: initLng +3,
east: initLat -3,
west: initLng -3,
};
  historicalOverlay = new google.maps.GroundOverlay(
 "https://storage.googleapis.com/geo-devrel-public-buckets/newark_nj_1922-661x516.jpeg",
 imageBounds
);
 historicalOverlay.setMap(map);
 }
 declare global {
 interface Window {
 initMap: () => void;
   }
 }
window.initMap = initMap;
export {};`
```